# gsub { $1.upcase } ? Is equivalent to .capitalize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, legacy

I found in the legacy code the following:

`"myString".sub(/^(.)/) {$1.upcase}` seems very weird. While executing in IRB, I got the same result as `"myString".capitalize`

Wasn't able to find the documentation... so ended up on SO

Comment: Your title and question don't match. Are you interested in `gsub` or `sub`? They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly,

```
 "myString".capitalize
 #=> "Mystring"

 "myString".sub(/^(.)/) {$1.upcase}
 #=> "MyString"
```

From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) for `capitalize`

> Returns a copy of str with the first character converted to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase. Note: case conversion is effective only in ASCII region.

Answer (score 1):

`sub` accepts an optional block instead of a replacement parameter. If given, it places the sub-matches into global variables, invokes the block, and returns the matched portion of the string with the block's return value.

The regular expression in question finds the first character at the beginning of a line. It places that character in `$1` because it's contained in a sub-match `()`, invokes the block, which returns `$1.upcase`.

As an aside, this is a brain-dead way of capitalizing a string. Even if you didn't know about `.capitalize` or this code is from *before* `.capitalize` was available (?), you could still have simply done `myString[0] = myString[0].upcase`. The only possible benefit is the `.sub` method will work if the string is empty, where `""[0].upcase` will raise an exception. Still, the better way of circumventing *that* problem is `myString[0] = myString[0].upcase if myString.length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Both are not exactly same. [sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-sub) is used to replace the first occurrence of the pattern specified, whereas [gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) does it for all occurrences (that is, it replaces globally).

In your question, regular expression is the first character i.e., `$1` and replaces with `$1.upcase`.

**CODE :**

```
"myString".sub(/^(.)/) {$1.upcase}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
"MyString"
```

**CODE :**

```
"myString".capitalize
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
"Mystring"
```